# SPSS changing count totals

Tags: data-analysis, spss, survey

I am running crosstabs from a survey in SPSS - Layered 2 independent variables on one question (the dependent variable). There are 1000 responses total, but whenever I run the crosstab it returns the data with 1001 or 999 or 1002 responses total. I have tried using both the Custom Tables feature and the Descriptive Crosstab feature. Neither will give me the correct totals, and all of the counts are just barely off. Is this a common problem? How do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question. I've also wondered about that. https://stats.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to find an answer.

Comment: crosstab soesn't count missing values - that could account for smaller totals, but bigger totals?? are you using wighting? (you should see "weight on" at the bottom right of the data window)